# Laravel find out diffrent queues

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-artisan, worker

I have different Laravel instances. My plan is to list how much jobs in each queue is. With `Queue::size()` or Queue::size('some_queue') I can detect it.

My Problem now is how to find out what diffrent Queues in a specific Laravel instance exist.

In my view I could iterate it like

`foreach($queues as $queue){ echo $queue . ': ' . Queue::size($qeue);}`

The question is, how I can find out the content of `$queues`? Or any better way?

Comment: I don't think laravel keeps tracks of what queues you created, you probably need to do that yourself somewhere

Comment: What is your queue driver ?

Comment: just redis. maybe we can get it by listen with the keys starts with "queue"